# Is there a way to sort strings in the colums in alphabetical order in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

The column in spotfire have strings such as CDBAF, Is there a way where this string can be sorted in alphabetical order, eg: CDBAF to ABCDF

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by using R (aka *datafunction*):

1. Add a new input parameter, as table, to your script, that will be your table, lets call it `df`.
2. Add a new output parameter, as table, lets call it `df`.
3. Put the code below in your script:

---

Assuming your column has the name `unsortedString` :

```
df$sortedString <- vapply(df$unsortedString, function(xi) paste(sort(strsplit(xi, NULL)[[1]]), collapse=''), '')
```

---

4. Save the datafunction
5. Set your table for the df input table
6. Set a *new table* as output table
7. Use the *new table* in your new visualization
8. Set autorefresh to `on` in your datafunction settings

Comment: If it solves your problem, feel free to upvote and accept this answer ;)